# T-SQL Query Returning NULL Rows Using APPLY Operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm working on an SQL query which combines information if ServiceStart and ServiceEnd overlap with another entry for that provider. For the most part, the query is working, however, I'm getting a lot of NULL rows back.

I believe this may have something to do with using the OUTER APPLY. However, changing the OUTER APPLY to CROSS APPLY doesn't work either. I've also attempted to specify within the query WHERE ServiceID IS NOT NULL. The results are the same either way. Below I've provided a screen shot of the results currently being returned as well as a link to rextester.com with full code.

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME, @EndTime DATETIME
SET @StartTime = '2018-11-01'
SET @EndTime = '2018-11-05'
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT c.ClaimID, 
                c.ProvidedBy, 
                c.StartTime, 
                c.EndTime, 
                oa.ServiceStart, 
                oa.ServiceEnd, 
                c.ClaimDetailID, 
                c.ServiceID, 
                c.Duration
         FROM tbl_Claims c
              OUTER APPLY
         (
             SELECT MIN(t2.StartTime) ServiceStart, 
                    MAX(t2.EndTime) ServiceEnd
             FROM tbl_Claims t2
             WHERE t2.StartTime <= c.EndTime
                   AND (t2.EndTime >= c.StartTime)
            AND (t2.ServiceID <> 0 and c.ServiceID <> 0)
            AND (t2.StartTime >= @StartTime AND t2.EndTime <= @EndTime)
            AND (t2.ProvidedBy = c.ProvidedBy)          
         ) oa)
     SELECT c.ProvidedBy, 
            c.ServiceStart, 
            c.ServiceEnd, 
            MAX(ca1.ClaimIDs) ClaimIDs, 
            MAX(ca2.ClaimDetailIDs) ClaimDetailIDs, 
            MAX(ca3.ServiceIDs) ServiceIDs
     FROM cte c
          CROSS APPLY
     (
         SELECT STUFF(
         (
             SELECT ', ' + CAST(p.[ClaimID] AS VARCHAR(40))
             FROM cte AS p
             WHERE p.ServiceStart = c.ServiceStart AND (p.ProvidedBy = c.ProvidedBy)
                    AND p.ServiceID <> 0
             ORDER BY p.ClaimID FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '')
     ) ca1(ClaimIDs)
          CROSS APPLY
     (
         SELECT STUFF(
         (
             SELECT ', ' + CAST(p.[ClaimDetailID] AS VARCHAR(40))
             FROM cte AS p
             WHERE p.ServiceStart = c.ServiceStart AND (p.ProvidedBy = c.ProvidedBy)
             AND p.ServiceID <> 0
             ORDER BY p.ClaimDetailID FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '')
     ) ca2(ClaimDetailIDs)
          CROSS APPLY
     (
         SELECT STUFF(
         (
             SELECT ', ' + CAST(p.[ServiceID] AS VARCHAR(40))
             FROM cte AS p
             WHERE p.ServiceStart = c.ServiceStart AND (p.ProvidedBy = c.ProvidedBy)
             AND p.ServiceID <> 0
             ORDER BY p.ClaimDetailID FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '')
     ) ca3(ServiceIDs)
     GROUP BY c.ProvidedBy, 
              c.ServiceStart, 
              c.ServiceEnd
     ORDER BY c.ProvidedBy, 
              c.ServiceStart, 
              c.ServiceEnd;
```

- The problem is: I'm getting null rows back as shown [image: here]
- The desired result is: As shown [here](https://rextester.com/CWBH87461) with complete code.

Comment: Please try to reduce the actual query to a minimal, complete and verifiable example. If your problem is just the redundant rows being returned, then try to simplify the query e.g. by removing some of the columns selected.

Comment: Is 'ProvidedBy' sometimes NULL?  I'm imagining that some of the claims in tbl_Claims do not link to anything in tbl_Claims  using the conditions you've got.  Presumably the results you get are based on data different to the data on the test bed, is that the case?  Do you just want to 'throw away' the nulls?  If that's the case, make the main query into the next part of the cte, then filter it.

Comment: @Cato I was able to determine there was a single record in tbl_Claims that didn't have a ProvidedBy ID, which I'll have to assure that doesn't happen again. However, would you please expand on "Make the main query into the next part of the cte?"

Comment: @TrentAdams - hi, WITH CTE AS (....) , CTE2 AS (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE <appropriate checks to remove nulls>) Select FROM CTE2